# Android Development Training Advance | problem with mRadius = (float) (Math.min(mWidth, mHeight) / 2 * 0.8)

Tags: android, geometry, android-custom-view, radius

I was studying the advanced android course, more specifically in this codelab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-custom-view-from-scratch?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#2

I don't get why radius is calculated in that form, I don't understand how they calculate the radius. Why is there a 0.8 in this formula:

mRadius = (float) (Math.min(mWidth, mHeight) / 2 * 0.8)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `0.8` in this case defines, how much of the available space of the device, the circle should cover.

I think this is easiest explained using an example. Say our canvas width is 400 pixel and the height is 640 pixel. Because 400 is smaller the calculation would be:

```java
mRadius = (float) (400/2)
```

this will result in a radius of 200 and the circle would therefore cover all available width. (Because there is an imaginary * 1 in the formula)

In this tutorial however the circle should have a margin. Setting (brackets are for clarity only)

```java
mRadius = (float) ((400/2) * 0.8)
```

will result in a radius (and a circle) that covers only 80% of the available space.